# Bytebuddy: Is it possible to intercept a method by replacing the execution with a lambda expression?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

**Is it possible to intercept a method by replacing the execution with a lambda expression, or a non-static method from some other class?**

Ex 1:

```
installByteBuddyAgent();

byteBuddy
        .redefine(sourceClass) //This is important, i need to change a class definition
        .method(named(methodName))
        .intercept({{expression}})
        .make()
        .load(
                sourceClass.getClassLoader(),
                ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

//expression = Lambda expression that would be executed in place of the original method, or call a (non-static) method from some other class.
```

***The intention is to avoid writing a class with a static method to perform the interception.***

Ex 2:

```
    public class A {
        public void sayHello() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }

    public class B {
        public void sayGoodbye() {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
        }
    }
    
// ...

    @Test
    void interceptAReplacingByB() {
        final Class<A> sourceClass = A.class;
        final B b = Mockito.spy(new B());
        
        byteBuddy
                .redefine(sourceClass)
                .method(named("sayHello"))
                .intercept( /*call sayGoodbye from B or create a lambda expression to do it*/ )
                .make()
                .load(
                        sourceClass.getClassLoader(),
                        ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
        
        new A().sayHello();
        
        Mockito.verify(b).sayGoodbye();
    }
```

This code snippet does not represent the complete scenario. It was only built to exemplify the issue.

The interception of public methods can be done in other ways, but the objective is not to work only with public methods, or only with test scenarios.

Comment: I’m not sure what you want. Perhaps, you want to use [`InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(InvocationHandler)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/latest/net/bytebuddy/implementation/InvocationHandlerAdapter.html#of-java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler-). Since `InvocationHandler` is a functional interface, you could implement it using a lambda expression.

Comment: I put one more example to try to explain the hypothesis that I would like to work on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting you right:

```
// ...
.intercept(net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall.invoke("sayGoodbye").on(b))
// ...
```

Note that [a `static` field will be defined in your reimplementation of `A` to hold the instance of `b`](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/b175b6722f38fba61d20ba04429c262c1b73ea1f/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.java#L2228-L2285).

Comment: Error invoking java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#retransformClasses
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#retransformClasses
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)

Comment: Good luck.  I see that you are blending redefining classes with agents which is a use case I don't have experience with.